# auth.net - Prior Auth Capture in Test Mode

Tags: authorize.net

I'm attempting to use Auth.net to authorize a transaction, then later capture it with prior_auth_capture. This works fine in a sandbox, but running against production in test mode I get some problems:

```
PRODUCTION_TESTMODE : Transaction Id: 0 
PRODUCTION_TESTMODE : CC Authorization is APPROVED for 41.0 - customer Test User. 
PRODUCTION_TESTMODE : Auth Code: 000000 
Credit card transaction was successful - card was approved for 41.00.
```

Later, when we try to capture the transaction, we have a problem because auth.net won't accept the transaction ID 0:

```
PRODUCTION_TESTMODE : CC Capture is ERROR for 41.0 - transaction ID 0 
PRODUCTION_TESTMODE : RRC_3_33 : (TESTMODE) A valid referenced transaction ID is required. 
Credit card capture was not successful - reason: (TESTMODE) A valid referenced transaction ID is required.
```

I haven't been successful in finding any documentation around this. Is it normal that prior_auth_capture fails like this in test mode? Is there a way we can handle this, or must we check for transaction ID == 0 and introduce special handling here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be running in Live Mode to process transactions.

Test mode doesn't actually process a transaction, it simply validates that the API Login and Transaction Key are correct for the targeted endpoint, and returns success.